# The requested URL /about-us was not found on this server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

After executing the export, on the host, when I enter the link manually or refresh the page, a message is not displayed.
I have the server.js and the next module. Do I need to do anything else?

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const { parse } = require('url');

const DEV = process.env.ENVIRONMENT !== 'production';
const PORT = 4567;

const app = next({dir: '.', dev: DEV});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const getRoutes = require('./routes');

const routes = getRoutes();
app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;
    const route = routes[pathname];
    if (route) {
      return app.render(req, res, route.page, route.query);
    }
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(PORT, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> READY FOR LIFOTFF http://localhost:${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

**Router.js**

```
module.exports = () => {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' },
      '/404': { page: '/404' },
      '/about-us': { page: '/about-us' },
      
    }
  }
```

**next.config.js**

```
const getRoutes = require('./routes');
module.exports = {
    useFileSystemPublicRoutes: true,
    exportPathMap: getRoutes

  }
```

Comment: Since you're using `exportPathMap` I assume you're exporting your app as [static HTML](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) with `next export`, which means you don't need a custom server setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add `trailingSlash: true` to next.config.js,it's working.

my new **next.config**:

```
const getRoutes = require('./routes');
module.exports = {
    trailingSlash: true, 
    useFileSystemPublicRoutes: true,
    exportPathMap: getRoutes,
    serverRuntimeConfig: {
      // Will only be available on the server side
      mySecret: 'secret',
      secondSecret: process.env.SECOND_SECRET, // Pass through env variables
    },
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
      // Will be available on both server and client
      staticFolder: '/static',
    },

  }
```